# Paypal sandbox account unauthorized

Tags: ruby, paypal, paypal-sandbox

For development purpose, I have create a main account as developper and also create a "sandbox" account. This account is also declared in my dashboard as SandBox account in the v.zero section.

In my app, I have added a file configs/paypal.yaml with the updated information for client_id, client_secret.... it looks like as below:

```
test: &default
  client_id: Af9L4GJ7xxxxtp4wPQFqkL03bYYWuFius
  client_secret: xxxxxx*//*
  username: first.last_api2.corp.com
  password: YEQZF7KGCY5SFFGC
  signature: AFcWxV21C7fd0DDDDDSRl31ADLwdbXazZRfAA1zsZFfI4630wJS
  app_id: Braintree-1478556332407
  http_timeout: 120
  mode: sandbox
  sandbox_email_address: first.last@corp.com

development:
  <<: *default

with_authentication:
  <<: *default
  client_id: Af9L4GJ7xxxxtp4wPQFqkL03bYYWuFius
  client_secret: xxxxxx*//*
```

my apps is wrote in ruby, and after having put this paypal.yaml on my config/ repos, I have develop the ruby code to initiate a payout:

```
def send_payment params
       begin
         payout = PayPal::SDK::REST::Payout.new(get_payout_attributes params)
         @@logger.info("Create a new Payout #{payout}")
         result = payout.create(true)
         @@logger.info("Sending Payout: #{result}")
       rescue PayPal::SDK::Core::Exceptions => err
         @@logger.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
         @@logger.info("Error #{err}")
         @@logger.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
       end
       result
    end
```

get_payout_attributes are just used to get some customised data such as receiver, amout...

Any idea why I get the internal failure ??? failed or is it coming from the code.

I do not face any unauthorized user, but an Error failed - Error Code = 500 - Response message = Internal Server Error

the issue seems coming from the `payout.create(true)` as I get a (Response[500]: Internal Server Error) because the `PayPal::SDK::REST::Payout.new` do not generate any issues (Response[200]: OK)

Internal error do not give me much details

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not your code, but a PayPal issue.

Check out https://www.paypal-notify.com for status on production and sandbox servers. As of right now there is an alert for issues in the sandbox environment affecting the REST API.